# NativeScript Sidekick: "No matching version found for tns-android@0.0.1"

Tags: android, nativescript-angular, sidekick

After installing AndroidStudio, I could start the Android Emulator Nexus 5X, but when trying to run my NativeScript project in Sidekick, I get "Error detected during LiveSync on emulator-5554: No matching version found for tns-android@0.0.1". Has anyone an idea where this could come from? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to set a current version (5.3.1) in package.json, then it worked.

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": "otp.kis.mobile",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.3.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "0.0.1"
    }
  },
```